# Check irreducibility of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, minimal-polynomials

**Problem**: It is known that the minimal polynomial of an element $a \in F_4$ equals $x^2 + x + 1$. Does it follow from this that the polynomial $x^3 + ax^2 + a$ is irreducible in the ring of polynomials $F_4$[x]?

**Idea**: A polynomial of degree three over a field is reducible if and only if it has a root. Since there are only four elements in the field, we can list it: $a, a + 1, 1, 0$.
Substituting all these numbers in $p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + a$, we are convinced that they do not make this polynomial zero. Thus, $p(0) = a, p(1) = 1, p(a) = a, p(a + 1) = a$. 
But I am not sure whether this solution is correct.

Comment: The approach is correct; however, your computation is wrong: $p(a+1) = a^2 + a + 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a+1$ is a root of the given polynomial $P=x^3+ax^2+a$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(a+1) &=
(a+1)^3 +a(a+1)^2+a
\\
&=(a+1)^2(\ a+1+a\ ) +a
\\
&=(a+1)^2 +a
\\
&=(a^2+1^2) +a
\\
&=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer support, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: F.<a> = GF(2^2)
sage: a.minpoly()
x^2 + x + 1
sage: P = x^3 + a*x^2 + a 
sage: P.roots()
[(a + 1, 1)]
sage: P(a+1)
0
sage: P.factor()
(x + a + 1) * (x^2 + x + a + 1)
```